# Windows Rdp stopped working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

One of our servers mysteriously stopped accepting rdp connection this week. We did apply some updates in December 2012. So I thought the solution provided at  http://msitpros.com/?p=1293  would solve our problem. But rdp still didn't work after removing KB2667402.

The server is pingable, and telnet to port 3389 also worked. So, it should not be firewall or network issue.

Are there any other places I should be looking?

Thanks.

Comment: "Doesn't work" can mean a lot of things, clarification is needed.  Maybe your server's just too busy with getting a degree and trying to raise a baby to handle a job at this point in time. :o

Comment: Sorry. The symptom is a modal box saying "The connection was lost due to a network error. Try connecting again ..."  I know it's not a network issue because both ping and telnet works.

Comment: `Are there any other places I should be looking?` - Yes, in the event log of your server. Check for related events and post their contents to your question.